# I dont know why this error that is coming up in my code (Roblox Studio)

Tags: roblox

Im new to coding so i dont know how to fix it
I am trying to make a code where if you have bought a door and rejoin the game it will automaticly delete itself, but when i join the game again it comes up with this error
Players.1puppies0.PlayerScripts.MainClient:55: attempt to index nil with 'Destroy'
It deletes the first 3 doors but the other ones dont destroy
Heres the code
The error is on line 55

```
local players = game:GetService("Players")

local tweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

local player = players.LocalPlayer
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local runService = game:GetService("RunService")

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local remotes = replicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Remotes")
local mainSS = player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui"):WaitForChild("MainSS")
local doorPurchaseUI = mainSS:WaitForChild("PurchaseArea")
local despawnedDrops = replicatedStorage:WaitForChild("DespawnedDrops")
local currencyDropper = require(script.Parent:WaitForChild("CurrencyDroper"))

local areaBuyBtnConnection
local db = {}
local distance = 50

local function destroyDrop(drop)
    local result = remotes.AwardOnDestroy:InvokeServer(drop.Name, drop.PrimaryPart.CFrame)
    task.wait(0.2)
    local oldParent = drop.Parent
    drop.Parent = despawnedDrops
    task.wait(2)
    drop.Health.Value = drop.MaxHealth.Value
    drop.HealthDisplay.Enabled = false
    drop.Parent = oldParent
end

remotes.DropCoins.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(cf, guids)
    currencyDropper.DropCurrency(replicatedStorage.Assests.CurrencyDrops.CoinDrop, math.random(5, 20), cf + Vector3.new(0, 4, 0), guids)
end)

remotes.PromptPurchaseDoor.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(door)
    doorPurchaseUI.Visible = true
    doorPurchaseUI.PurchaseText.Text = "Would you like to purchase this area for "..door.Price.Value.." Coins"
    
    areaBuyBtnConnection = doorPurchaseUI.Buy.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        local result = remotes.PurchaseDoor:InvokeServer(door)
        if result == true then
            door:Destroy()
        end
        areaBuyBtnConnection:Disconnect()
        doorPurchaseUI.Visible = false
    end)
end)

remotes.ToggleBillboard.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(drop, bool)
    drop.HealthDisplay.Enabled = bool
end)

remotes.RemoveDoor.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(door)
    door:Destroy()
end)

doorPurchaseUI.Close.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    doorPurchaseUI.Visible = false
end)



task.spawn(function()
    while task.wait(1) do
        if player.Values.SentTo.Value ~= nil then
            local damage = player.Values.Damage.Value
            player.Values.SentTo.Value.Health.Value = math.max(player.Values.SentTo.Value.Health.Value - damage, 0)
            if player.Values.SentTo.Value.Health.Value == 0 then
                remotes.StopDamaging:FireServer()
                destroyDrop(player.Values.SentTo.Value)
            end
        end
    end
end)

runService.Heartbeat:Connect(function()
    for _, drop in pairs(workspace:WaitForChild("MainFolder_Workspace"):WaitForChild("Drops"):GetDescendants()) do
        if drop:IsA("Model") then
            local healthDisplay = drop:FindFirstChild("HealthDisplay")
            local bar = healthDisplay.Background.Bar
            local healthDisplayText = healthDisplay.Background.HealthDisplayLabel
            
            healthDisplayText.Text = drop.Health.Value
            bar:TweenSize(UDim2.fromScale(drop.Health.Value/drop.MaxHealth.Value, 1), Enum.EasingDirection.Out, Enum.EasingStyle.Sine, 0.3)
        end
    end
end)

runService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    
    if character then
        for _, v in pairs(workspace:WaitForChild("MainFolder_Workspace"):WaitForChild("CurrencyDrops"):GetChildren()) do
            if (v.Position - character.PrimaryPart.Position).Magnitude <= distance and v:FindFirstChild("CanCollect") then
                v.Anchored = true
                tweenService:Create(v, TweenInfo.new(0.2), {CFrame = character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame}):Play()
                if (v.Position - character.PrimaryPart.Position).Magnitude <= 3 then
                    if not db[v] then
                        db[v] = true
                        
                        remotes.GiveCoins:FireServer(v.ID.Value)
                        task.wait(5)
                        db[v] = nil
                    end
                    v:Destroy()
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

I dont know why its not working since im new to coding
I expected the code to work and destroy all the doors not only the first 3

Comment: https://devforum.roblox.com/t/attempt-to-index-nil-with-destroy/522750 Might help. Try to do some research on your own before asking stack.